# Use AutoCompleteComboBox as a parameter

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I did a Look-up list in LightSwitch - when I use this item at parameter level, it's not using the 'AutoCompleteComboBox' as the grid does.

How can I do it?

Here is the image for easy understanding

[image: Structure of LS screen]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the parameter and then in the properties you change the choice list

Image for demonstration

[image]